# Short jump and large jump with Strength of Keyboard input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I met problem when I jumped GameObject. I already make the Action largjump and shortjump. But the problem is how can I make Conditional Statement. I want to distinguish weak keyboard input, and strong keyboard input.

Here is my code.

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
{
    float JumpTime = 0;
    JumpTime = JumpTime + Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && JumpTime < 0.3f)
    {
        playerCtrl.ActionShortJump();
    }
    else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && JumpTime > 0.3f)
    {
        playerCtrl.ActionJump();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`GetButtonDown` only returns true the first frame the button is pressed, so you will never jump since the button cannot be down and up on the same frame. You will need to use `GetButton` to increase the jump time while the button is held down, and `GetButtonDown` to reset the timer when the button is first pressed, while also declaring the `JumpTime` outside of the overall method.

```
float JumpTime;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
       JumpTime = 0;
    if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        JumpTime += Time.deltaTime; 
    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && JumpTime > 0 && JumpTime < 0.3f)
        playerCtrl.ActionShortJump();
    else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && JumpTime > 0 && JumpTime > 0.3f)
        playerCtrl.ActionJump();
    else
        JumpTime = 0;
}
```